# Do I have to change the package name of com.amazonaws.mobilehelper to something else for the AWS MobileHub example

Tags: android, aws-mobilehub

I am using the MobileHub example app v0.16 to build my own app with it. I changed the application ID in build.gradle (Module:app). Do I also have to modify the package in the AWSMobileHelper manifest to avoid conflicts with other apps?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the package name for the AWSMobileHelper module should not be required. However, it should be different from your app's package name. The application ID for an app needs to be unique, however the package name does not. Package names must be unique within each app you are compiling; so for example, you cannot depend on two android modules that both use the same package name.